# Notice: Undefined variable: mine in C:\wamp\www\social\profile-view.php on line 58

Tags: php, undefined

I'm getting this error on my page. I tried to comment out the "$mine" but it then allows me to add my own profile. I need to say that if the page or user isn't me, then show the add or remove friend option. Any suggestions? I got this code from this youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wgbmgf84ZOo

```
<?php
    require_once('includes/class-query.php');
    require_once('includes/class-insert.php');


    if ( !empty ( $_POST ) ) {
        if ( $_POST['type'] == 'add' ) {
            $add_friend = $insert->add_friend($_POST['user_id'], $_POST['friend_id']);
        }

        if ( $_POST['type'] == 'remove' ) {
            $remove_friend = $insert->remove_friend($_POST['user_id'], $_POST['friend_id']);
        }
    }

    $logged_user_id = 1;


    if ( !empty ( $_GET['uid'] ) ) {
        $user_id = $_GET['uid'];
        $user = $query->load_user_object($user_id);

        if ( $logged_user_id == $user_id ) {

        }
    } else {
        $user = $query->load_user_object($logged_user_id);

    }

    $friends = $query->get_friends($logged_user_id);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/social">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="profile-view.php">View Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="profile-edit.php">Edit Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="friends-directory.php">Member Directory</a></li>
                <li><a href="friends-list.php">Friends List</a></li>
                <li><a href="feed-view.php">View Feed</a></li>
                <li><a href="feed-post.php">Post Status</a></li>
                <li><a href="messages-inbox.php">Inbox</a></li>
                <li><a href="messages-compose.php">Compose</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h1>View Profile</h1>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Name: <?php echo $user->user_nicename; ?></p>
            <p>Email Address: <?php echo $user->user_email; ?></p>
            <?php if ( !$mine ) : ?>
                <?php if ( !in_array($user_id, $friends) ) : ?>
                    <p>
                        <form method="post">
                            <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $logged_user_id; ?>" />
                            <input name="friend_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" />
                            <input name="type" type="hidden" value="add" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Add as Friend" />
                        </form>
                    </p>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <p>
                        <form method="post">
                            <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $logged_user_id; ?>" />
                            <input name="friend_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" />
                            <input name="type" type="hidden" value="remove" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Remove Friend" />
                        </form>
                    </p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is Google broken or something?

Comment: possible user didn't finish the tutorial?

Comment: @Class He did but the code is acting weird.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus jokes on you, I use Ixquick

Comment: Oh my bad. Is lxquick broken or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a notice, not a fatal error. the line if(!$mime) is returning the notice. Change it to if(!isset($mime)) and the error will be suppressed:

```
<p>Email Address: <?php echo $user->user_email; ?></p>
            <?php if ( !isset($mine) ) : ?>
                <?php if ( !in_array($user_id, $friends) ) : ?>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! you are awesome!! I had tried the isset command but I forgot to put the "!" in front of it. I feel so stupid. Once again thank you!